# Row wise count of Zeros' and NA in R for Columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to find count of rows with respect to number of Zero's and NA's in the data frame , for example
number of rows having zeros in only 1 column etc..

code for the df is below and need to find for columns from M1 to M5

O/P needed for Zeros and NA , link provided below for desired O/P
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFO6t.jpg

```
id <- 1:9
M1 <- c(0,NA,1,0,0,NA,NA,1,7)
M2 <- c(NA,NA,0,NA,0,NA,NA,1,7)
M3 <- c(1,NA,0,0,0,1,NA,1,7)
M4 <- c(0,NA,0,3,0,NA,NA,1,7)
M5 <- c(5,0,0,NA,0,0,NA,0,NA)
data <- cbind(id,M1,M2,M3,M4,M5)
data <- as.data.frame(data)
```

Desired Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
table(rowSums(is.na(data)))

# 0 1 2 3 4 5 
# 3 2 1 1 1 1 

table(factor(rowSums(data == 0, na.rm = T), levels = 0:5))

# 0 1 2 3 4 5 
# 2 3 2 0 1 1
```

You can also pass the codes above to `data.frame()` or `as.data.frame()` to get an `data.frame` object like your expected output shows.

Answer (score 1):

For NA:

```
data.frame(table(rowSums(is.na(data[startsWith(names(data),"M")]))))
  Var1 Freq
1    0    3
2    1    2
3    2    1
4    3    1
5    4    1
6    5    1
```

For zeros

```
data.frame(table(factor(rowSums(0==data[startsWith(names(data),"M")],TRUE),0:5)))
  Var1 Freq
1    0    2
2    1    3
3    2    2
4    3    0
5    4    1
6    5    1
```

Comment: Wow I'm slower for few seconds! +1

Comment: @Tsai its perfectly fine. Actually your code does everything needed. So its okay Will give you your +1 back haha

Answer (score 0):

My solution is kind of complicated, but it gives the desired output using `apply` functions:

```
myFun <- function(data, count, fun) {
  applyFun <- function(x) {
    length(which(
      apply(data, 1, function(y) length(which(fun(y))) == x)
    ))
  }
  sapply(count, applyFun)
}
myFun(data, 0:5, is.na)
myFun(data, 0:5, function(x) x == 0)
```

(You made a mistake in your example: two rows have no zeroes in any column: rows 7 and 9.)

Answer (score 0):

```
apply(data, 1, function(x) length(x[is.na(x)]))
```

This will give you a vector. Each element corresponds to a row and its value is the number of NA elements in that row.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a for loop option to count NAs and Zeros in each row and then use `dplyr::count` to summarize the frequency of each value.

```
data$CountNA<-NA
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
  data[i,"CountNA"]<-length(which(is.na(data[i,1:(ncol(data)-1)])))}
count(data, CountNA)

data$CountZero<-NA
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
  data[i,"CountZero"]<-length(which((data[i,1:(ncol(data)-2)]==0)))}
count(data, CountZero)
```